# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' trying to convert input to float

Tags: python

I am a python beginner, this code is supposed to be simple. I am supposed to create a tip calculator that accepts input from the user about how much the meal was and then a percentage they would like to leave. The "main" was provided to me and I am supposed to define two functions that convert meal total to a float and percentage wanting to leave as a tip to a float. I have been stuck on this problem for a while and can't figure where I am going wrong.

```py
def main():
    dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
    percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
    tip = dollars * percent
    print(f"Leave ${tip:.2f}")
```

These two def functions are where I'm hung up:

```py
def dollars_to_float(d):
    d = d.replace("$" , "")
    df = float(d)
    print(df)

def percent_to_float(p):
    p = p.replace("%" , "")
    pf = float(p/100)
    print(pf)

main()
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
(TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int') with this code
```

Comment: `float(p/100)` Convert `p` to a number before doing the division: `float(p) / 100`

Comment: The error message is pointing you to the problem: `p` is still a string, so it isn't going to work with a division operator. The `/` does *not* perform any implicit string-to-number conversions.

Comment: By the way, you will need your two conversion functions to have a `return` instead of a `print()`. That will sort out your next error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def dollars_to_float(d):
    d = d.replace("$", "")
    df = float(d)
    return df


def percent_to_float(p):
    p = float(p.replace("%", ""))
    pf = p / 100
    return pf


def main():
    dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
    percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
    tip = dollars * percent
    print(f"Leave ${tip:.2f}")

main()
```

Notes:

1. as @Johnny said you have to convert your variable to float
2. your functions have to return values

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue, I was using print to test if my values were being turn to float. However, in the first lecture that this assignment is on we weren't introduced to return. I had no clue...